# iptables nat table does not work as expected?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

I aim to have some iptables rules to observe the flow of network traffic through iptables rules. However, iptables does not seem to work as I expected. It appears that packets which are the response of a request does not respect NAT table rules.

First of all, I have created some rules that logs into `syslog` matched packets. Here are my `NAT` table rules:

```
# iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.1/32 -j LOG --log-prefix "+++ nat, preroute +++"
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.2/32 -j LOG --log-prefix "+++ nat, output +++"
-A POSTROUTING -d 10.0.0.2/32 -j LOG --log-prefix "+++ nat, postrouting ++++"
```

And these are my `filter` table rules:

```
# iptables -t filter -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A INPUT -d 10.0.0.1/32 -j LOG --log-prefix "+++ filter, input +++"
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.2/32 -j LOG --log-prefix "++++ filter, output ++++"
```

`raw`, `mangle` and `security` tables are clear:

```
# iptables -t raw -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# iptables -t mangle -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT

# iptables -t security -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

In order to test my rules I have created a network namespace using the following script. It creates a network namespace along with a pair of veth interfaces that one of its peers is attached to network namespace:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -ex 

ip netns add net1

ip link add veth1 type veth peer veth2 netns net1

ip link set veth1 up
ip netns exec net1 ip link set veth2 up
ip netns exec net1 ip link set lo up

ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev veth1
ip netns exec net1 ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev veth2
```

Then I ping my localhost using `veth` interface from `net1` namespace:

```
# ip netns exec net1 ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.106 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.088 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.085 ms
```

According to this [image](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/images/tables_traverse.jpg), which is part of this [blog](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html), I expect to see the following message logs in `syslog`:

```
+++ nat, preroute +++      -> for first packet destined to 10.0.0.1
+++ filter, input +++      -> for first packet destined to 10.0.0.1 
+++ nat, output +++        -> for first response packet destined to 10.0.0.2
+++ nat, postrouting ++++  -> for first response packet destined to 10.0.0.2
```

However, `syslog` logs differ:

```
May  1 10:46:35 safdarian-Legion-5-15ITH6 kernel: [ 4165.810315] +++ nat, preroute +++IN=veth1 OUT= MAC=1a:31:55:32:60:0d:2e:bb:08:2b:8b:5e:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.2 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=10280 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=37055 SEQ=1 
May  1 10:46:35 safdarian-Legion-5-15ITH6 kernel: [ 4165.810327] +++ filter, input +++IN=veth1 OUT= MAC=1a:31:55:32:60:0d:2e:bb:08:2b:8b:5e:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.2 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=10280 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=37055 SEQ=1 
May  1 10:46:35 safdarian-Legion-5-15ITH6 kernel: [ 4165.810341] ++++ filter, output ++++IN= OUT=veth1 SRC=10.0.0.1 DST=10.0.0.2 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=27366 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=37055 SEQ=1 
May  1 10:46:36 safdarian-Legion-5-15ITH6 kernel: [ 4166.813517] +++ filter, input +++IN=veth1 OUT= MAC=1a:31:55:32:60:0d:2e:bb:08:2b:8b:5e:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.2 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=10332 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=37055 SEQ=2 
May  1 10:46:36 safdarian-Legion-5-15ITH6 kernel: [ 4166.813538] ++++ filter, output ++++IN= OUT=veth1 SRC=10.0.0.1 DST=10.0.0.2 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=27433 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=37055 SEQ=2 
May  1 10:46:37 safdarian-Legion-5-15ITH6 kernel: [ 4167.837538] +++ filter, input +++IN=veth1 OUT= MAC=1a:31:55:32:60:0d:2e:bb:08:2b:8b:5e:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.2 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=10508 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=37055 SEQ=3 
May  1 10:46:37 safdarian-Legion-5-15ITH6 kernel: [ 4167.837558] ++++ filter, output ++++IN= OUT=veth1 SRC=10.0.0.1 DST=10.0.0.2 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=27527 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=37055 SEQ=3
```

Can someone please explain why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iptables NAT is **stateful** and per-flow rather than per-packet.

Only the *first* packet of a flow (that is, packets belonging to an unknown flow) is sent through the 'nat' table – all subsequent packets bypass it, as they are recognized by the conntrack<sup>1</sup> subsystem which automatically applies the same translation, or reverse translation for replies.

So the "Echo Reply" packet that would match `-d 10.0.0.2/32` never hits the 'POSTROUTING' chain (or 'PREROUTING' for that matter<sup>2</sup>) because it was recognized as belonging to an existing ICMP flow and automatically skipped the whole 'nat' table.

("Flows" are directly mapped to connections in TCP or SCTP, but for connection-less L4 protocols like UDP or ICMP they are established implicitly, with some sort of timeout; for example, all UDP packets between the same src:sport⇆dst:dport are part of the same flow until it expires.)

You can use `conntrack -L` to see the flow table; note how it has two sets of src/dst pairs, the original and the "reply to". (If you were to apply outbound DNAT in prerouting, for example, the inbound reply packets would match the "reply-to" fields and would be automatically SNATed accordingly.)

---

<sup>1</sup> This is exactly the same conntrack that implements `--state ESTABLISHED` commonly found in iptables filter rules, or `ct state` in nftables rules.

<sup>2</sup> Your rules, with those specific `-d` matches, look like they're written under the assumption that PREROUTING is only for outbound packets and POSTROUTING is only for inbound ones. That is not really the case – all packets will traverse *both* chains.